# Other packages conflict with GDAL

Tags: gdal, fedora

I have recently updated to fedora 28 and tried to install the latest version of gdal using `yum install gdal gdal-devel gdal-libs`. I tested this and it worked fine.

After installing other packages I type `gdalinfo --version` and I get the following error

```
gdalinfo: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: wrapper_dgbsvx_
```

What packages are interfering with gdal? Here is a list of what i've installed

```
python2-gdal
python-devel
grass
grass-devel
grass-gui
qgis
R

Geany
cmake
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm hoping you have fixed since then, but `libarmadillo` provides the missing `wrapper_dgbsvx` symbol. I then also had to update `ogdi` because of `ecs_SetReportErrorFunction` being required from there.